# How to make my Login Form work when pressing login?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Using JQuery, I have to create a Login Form that must meet certain requirements, but when I press submit, nothing happens. I wrote and rewrote this code so many times, and got my inspiration from several websites but in the end it's really a mess!

If the user enters the right username (new_user) or password (123456789), the field becomes green and it'll show the green check and a message like: Succesfull login!
Otherwise (wrong data or blank fields), the field turns red, showing a red cross and an error message (for example: Please insert a valid username, Please insert a valid password).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var validEmail = $("#username").val() === "new_user";
    var validPassword = $("#password").val() === "123456789";
    
    if (validEmail === true && validPassword === true) {
      $('input[type="text"],input[type="username"]').css("border", "2px solid green");
      $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border", "2px solid green");
      document.write("Login succesfull!"); 
      
<span class = "material-symbols-outlined" style = "color: green;"> check </span>
      
    } 
    else {
      $('input[type="text"],input[type="username"]').css("border", "2px solid red");
      $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border", "2px solid red");
      document.write("Please insert a valid username.");
      document.write("Please insert a valid password."); 
      
<span class = "material-symbols-outlined" style = "color: red;"> close </span>

    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#login-container {
  width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form label,
form input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form input {
  padding: 8px;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form div {
  margin: 16px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="login-container">
  <form id="formular" method="post">
    <div class="input">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input id="username" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" type="password">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
```

Thank you so much!

Heidi

Comment: There is many problems with your code. 1 you don't have an element with id `submit`, second `<span class="material-symbols-outlined" style="color: green;">check</span>` is not valid in your jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems throwing exceptions.

In the demo below I left your own approach and just changed the conditions to better trigger the validation separated on the single fields and the final response given via a message printed on an alert element below the input form.

Once the submit button is clicked, the validation is triggered styling each field accordingly (red/green) and showing the result of login (success/fail) with a message saying which fields, if any, required a different value.

For your further research I suggest to give an eye to the js console to understand what's going wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var validEmail = $("#username").val() == "new_user";
    var validPassword = $("#password").val() == "123456789";        

    let failureMsg = [];

    if (validEmail == true){      
      $('#username').css("border", "solid 2px green");
    }else{
      $('#username').css("border", "solid 2px red");
      failureMsg.push('Please insert a valid username.');
    }
    
    if (validPassword == true){      
      $('#password').css("border", "solid 2px green");
    }else{
      $('#password').css("border", "solid 2px red");
      failureMsg.push('Please insert a valid password.');
    }
    
    if(validPassword && validEmail){
      $('#output')
        .removeClass()
        .text('Login was successful!')
        .addClass('login_success');        
    }else{      
      $('#output')   
        .removeClass()
        .html(`Login failed!<hr>${failureMsg.join("<br>")}`)
        .addClass('login_fail');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#login-container {
  width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form label,
form input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form input {
  padding: 8px;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form div {
  margin: 16px 0px;
}

/*--rules added below--*/

#output{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  display: none;
}

#output hr{
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.login_success{
  color: #155724;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  border-color: #c3e6cb;  
  display: block !important;
}

.login_fail{
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
  display: block !important;
}

#submit{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="login-container">
  <form id="formular" method="post">
    <div class="input">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input id="username" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" type="password">
    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
</div>
```